# WPF Style/Template gets applied only to the last added element

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls

I have a simple control derived from `ContentControl` with this code:

```
public class HeaderFooterControl : ContentControl
{
    static HeaderFooterControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HeaderFooterControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HeaderFooterControl)));
    }

    public object Header
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Header.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(object), typeof(HeaderFooterControl));

    public object Footer
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(FooterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FooterProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Footer.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Footer", typeof(object), typeof(HeaderFooterControl));



    public string HeaderText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HeaderText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HeaderText", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderFooterControl));



    public string FooterText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(FooterTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FooterTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for FooterText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("FooterText", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderFooterControl));


}
```

It has customizable Header and Footer properties so user can attach any controls within.

The only window in this application defined like this:

```
<Window x:Class="CustomControlTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControlTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HeaderFooterControl}" x:Key="DefaultHeaderFooterStyle">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HeaderFooterControl}">
                        <Grid Background="Pink">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Footer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HeaderFooterControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultHeaderFooterStyle}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Header">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:HeaderFooterControl}}}" Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Footer">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FooterText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:HeaderFooterControl}}}" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:HeaderFooterControl HeaderText="H1" FooterText="F1" Margin="10"/>
        <local:HeaderFooterControl HeaderText="H2" FooterText="F2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10"/>
        <local:HeaderFooterControl HeaderText="H3" FooterText="F3" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Resources for this window define 2 styles for my custom control. The custom control displays header, main content and footer. By default header/footer are `TextBlock`s with it's `Text` properties bound to `HeaderText` or `FooterText` properties of `HeaderFooterControl`. The problem is that only last added `HeaderFooterControl` displays any content. Why is it so?

Comment: by content you mean Header/Footer text correct?

Comment: first of all - use TemplateBindings. Also try to create one combined style. Will it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found so far is to move content for header and footer parts into resources, then reference those resources from xaml code using `StaticResource` extention. All content are `UIElement`s so every instance should have `x:Shared="False"` attribute set so it will be created every time it's needed in VisualTree. Also check out this answer, it implies the same behaviour described https://stackoverflow.com/a/8702180/371967

```
<Window x:Class="CustomControlTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControlTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HeaderFooterControl}" x:Key="DefaultHeaderFooterStyle">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:HeaderFooterControl}">
                        <Grid Background="Pink">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Footer, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <TextBlock x:Key="DefaultHeaderContent" Text="{Binding HeaderText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:HeaderFooterControl}}}" Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Shared="False"/>
        <TextBlock x:Key="DefaultFooterContent" Text="{Binding FooterText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:HeaderFooterControl}}}" Background="Green" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Shared="False"/>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:HeaderFooterControl}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultHeaderFooterStyle}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{StaticResource DefaultHeaderContent}"/>
                <Setter Property="Footer" Value="{StaticResource DefaultFooterContent}"/>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:HeaderFooterControl HeaderText="H1" FooterText="F1" Margin="10"/>
        <local:HeaderFooterControl HeaderText="H2" FooterText="F2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10"/>
        <local:HeaderFooterControl HeaderText="H3" FooterText="F3" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```